# How to create a client of a WCF service in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on an application in xamarin android, i want to create a client of a wcf service, i added the service as a web refrence, it detected the service but i am unable to create a client, whenever i try to declare the service by its name, it doesn't get recognized.It is a locally hosted wcf service.

Wcf Service = "http://192.168.123.240/ClearSourceAndroid/FusionService.svc"

i checked the service using SoapUI and everything is working fine. How should i consume this service and access the methods in it.

screeshots:
[Working wcf service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOvQj.png)

[added it as a web refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGYPA.png)

[cannot create object of my wcf service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHPTQ.png)

Comment: I cant create a instance of the service sir, i wont post a similar question every now and i haven't found any answer yet. Please Help me with this

Comment: i have added the screenshots, i need a fix to this. please help me